# Replaced image not showing on image slider

Tags: image, slider

*Hi there,
I am currently making use of an existing code that includes javascript for implementing an image slider. It works for the existing images but when I try to replace with other pictures, the slider turns up blank everytime. There don't seems to be any problem with the code since its works again whenever I switch the pictures back to the original images.

I suspect there could be a problem with the code retrieving the new images properly after I have switched them but I am not sure.

Any idea what might have gone wrong?* In the CSS code, as you can see below, "banner" (for original image) works. But it fails to show for "banner1" and "banner2" which are the paths for the new images that I want to switch to.

```
/*--banner-starts--*/
.banner{
background:url(../images/bnr-1.jpg) no-repeat;
min-height:600px;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
}

.banner1{
background:url(../images/awesome-sunshine-trees11.jpg) no-repeat;
min-height:600px;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
}

.banner2{
background:url(images/road ahead graham hobbs.jpg) no-repeat;
min-height:600px;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the photos definitely exist in the folder you have referenced.

Also the url should be inside quote marks

```
background:url("../images/someimage.jpg");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

on a sidebar its not really good practice to include spaces in your image paths.

Comment: thanks for suggestions.

I have tried them including adding quote marks and checking the pics are located in the same folder (in fact they are already in the same folders as the other original pics) but it still doesn't work.

Additionally I have tried to rename the pics to be the same as the names of the original pics (ie. bnr-1) so that I might not need to change the css codes itself but the renamed images still don't show up on the slider.

Any other suggestions very much welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my raised issue, its seems the images managed to be shown after I switch the internet browser from MS edge (default in Windows 10) to MS explorer. I can see the updated pics after opening the html file with IE.

Thank you. Hope this helps others save some time should they encounter the same problem in future.